# magento blank admin after 1.9.0 to 1.9.1 ugrade

Tags: php, magento, ssh, upgrade

There are other posts similar to this but non that i can find with a solution

I have a test site that i decided to upgrade in Magento Connect
during the upgrade in Magento connect it timed out and was left with blank front and admin page
I used SSH and was able to complete the upgrades, (first time i had used SSH)
all completed successfully, reindexed, permissions set, cache and session cleared
also disable recompiler and cleared

frontend works but admin still blank
no error reporting on the screen, no error reporting in files (checked via FTP)

index.php - set error to All, uncommented ini, developer to true, added line to increase memory

admin still blank
any ideas?

Comment: blank page happens usually because of a php fatal error. have you tried disabling all modules?

Comment: Did you do a database restoration after the timeout or just continue where the timeout left off using ssh?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses, i continued with SSH where i had left off and also with the modules i moved all 3rd party modules into a disabled folder but not the rest, so i will experiment with them now, perhaps leave mage ones and disable the rest - i will update shortly

Comment: Moved all but Mage modules to disabled but still the same

Comment: @C1oudM check you Magento logs and error reports and enable error reporting.

Comment: UPDATE: So i created a fresh DB and uploaded the original DB and pointed the magento install to it, and the front end worked and the admin was blank so it seems that during the original failed update that some admin theme files 'disappeared', i had read this somewhere that someone had a similar issue, so as i have the original file structure - pre upgrade i have just copied the entire app directory across and i now have the admin login - minus css - normally i would have started a clean install but i'm determined to work this one out

Comment: So the upgrade actually broke some of the file structure - as above i decided to overwrite all app files but 14 of them failed, the reason is that some folders were renamed .php or the phmtl file ended with .pht or phtm instead - so i have corrected those, now investigating all files in the skin folder as the admin is still not displaying correctly (no css)

Comment: FIXED: As above i replaced all of the app files and found the errors details above, then overwrite all skin folders and files - and hey presto the admin is working perfectly

Comment: @C1oudM I am facing similar issue . Can you help me to resolve this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936063/magento-site-not-working-after-upgrading-extensions