# Magento site not working after upgrading extensions

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, magento2

I upgraded all the extensions that were showing in Magento Connect. I am new guy in Magento. Before upgrdation site was working perfectly. 
I am using it on Linux server. My admin panel and website both are unble to load.

It is available here **http://130.211.244.103/**. I did a lot of googling , edited my index.php , increased the memory limit

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
umask(0);
```

Kindly suggest me solution to this issue.

Edit :
I checked my system and replace my files with new magento files. But now
 `sudo service apache2 restart Job for apache2.service failed. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` . The system is unable to start apache

Comment: what is issue you are facing?

Comment: @urfusion @all I checked my system and replace my files with new magento files. But now `sudo service apache2 restart
Job for apache2.service failed. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` . The system is unable to start apache

Comment: your site is working now

Comment: @urfusion It was error due to apache and mysql. They automatically went down. BTW thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. goto "includes/config.php" and comment every line of code in it.
2. empty the "var/*" folder

Hopefully will work again.

Comment: Thanks @Keshav for replying. I tried your suggestion but it didn't worked. It was an error due to apache and mysql. My problem is now solved and I have mentioned the answer as a reply.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something useful in var/log/exception.log?

You can also go to your error folder and rename local.xml.sample to local.xml for direct error printing in your browser.

I would recommend to first update your extensions in your local testing environment.

Have you checked for compatibility of your extensions first?

Comment: Thanks @Link.de for replying. I tried your suggestion but it didn't worked. It was an error due to apache and mysql. My problem is now solved and I have mentioned the answer as a reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After digging into magento and some of my server's command. I solved my problem.

Automatically apache and mysql server stopped and they were not responding. 
So, I completely uninstalled apache using

`sudo apt-get remove apache2*`

& Reinstalled mysql

- remove MySQL:

  `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean`
- Then reinstall:

  `sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mysql-server
  sudo mysql_install_db
  sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`